# Get form data from controller in nested form widgets of flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created one form in flutter which is pretty long, so I created seperate widget of sub section of the form. the functionality of the sub-form in short is, it has one button `add more` which adds a new row of field as per the user requirement.

The issue is that sub-form is in seperate widget and I am not able to fetch the form data on click of submit. form validations are working as expected though...

##### main form widget

```dart
class ProductsForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductsForm({super.key});

  @override
  ProductsFormState createState() => ProductsFormState();
}

class ProductsFormState extends State<ProductsForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _productNameController = TextEditingController();
  // other controllers

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _submitForm() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      // Form is valid, perform form submission logic here

      // logic to get data from controller and add to json
      print(postData);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [

            """
            other form fields...
            """
            
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const FormTitle(text: 'Product Variants'),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(child: VariantList()),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: defaultPadding),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _submitForm,
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the sub form which has functionality to add new row as per the user requirement.

##### varient list widget

```dart
class VariantControllers {
  final TextEditingController size;
  final TextEditingController items;
  final TextEditingController cost;
  final TextEditingController mrp;

  VariantControllers(this.size, this.items, this.cost, this.mrp);
}

class VariantList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selectedUnit;

  const VariantList({super.key, required this.selectedUnit});

  @override
  State<VariantList> createState() => _VariantListState();
}

class _VariantListState extends State<VariantList> {
  final List<VariantControllers> variantControllers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    variantControllers.add(
      VariantControllers(
        TextEditingController(),
        TextEditingController(),
        TextEditingController(),
        TextEditingController(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget VariantRows(VariantControllers controllers, int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              child: DataRowInputField(
                controller: controllers.size,
              )),
          const SizedBox(width: defaultPadding / 2),
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: DataRowInputField(controller: controllers.items),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: defaultPadding / 2),
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: DataRowInputField(controller: controllers.cost),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: defaultPadding / 2),
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: DataRowInputField(controller: controllers.mrp),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: defaultPadding / 2),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (variantControllers.length > 1) {
                setState(() {
                  variantControllers.removeAt(index);
                });
              }
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.close_outlined,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(flex: 3, child: Text('Size')),
            SizedBox(width: defaultPadding / 2),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text('Items')),
            SizedBox(width: defaultPadding / 2),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text('Cost')),
            SizedBox(width: defaultPadding / 2),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text('MRP')),
            SizedBox(width: defaultPadding / 2),
            IconButton(onPressed: null, icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz_outlined)),
          ],
        ),
        ...variantControllers.asMap().entries.map(
              (entry) => VariantRows(entry.value, entry.key),
            ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                variantControllers.add(
                  VariantControllers(
                    TextEditingController(),
                    TextEditingController(),
                    TextEditingController(),
                    TextEditingController(),
                  ),
                );
              });
            },
            child:
                const Text("Add more", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I want to fetch the data from other widget but not sure how to procede for it. Any lead would be helpful, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the data for each TextField in a higher level service and pass an [onChanged](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html) method to each TextField that updates the corresponding value. Using this method you would not need to create a new TextEditingController for each new field.

For example:

```
ValueNotifier<double> size = ValueNotifier(0);

void setSize(double val){
  size.value = val;
}


class DataRowInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataRowInputField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (value) {
        setSize(double.parse(value));
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: 'Size'
      ),
    );
  }
}
```